# How do I store the output of an online survey, preferably to a text file?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, raspberry-pi

I use an online questionnaire service (like Survey Monkey) to run surveys. I've written a novel question type using JavaScript and HTML5 that allows respondents to draw a picture during the course of the survey (currently the data generated is 3x0-255 integers per canvas pixel).

For a variety of reasons, I can't get the questionnaire service to store this output, so I'd like to set up an Apache server on a Raspberry PI and add some code to my JavaScript which submits the data to this server, which could then store it in a text file (it would have to deal with 100's of users, perhaps simultaneously).

I'm familiar with python and cosmetic JavaScript/HTML, but I have no idea what I'd enter into google to try and learn what I need to, let alone where to begin. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide html source code from your example?

Comment: Sorry I can't - its something I use at work. However, if you could tell me what you'd be looking for, maybe I could provide more detail?

Comment: The api of the latest version of javascript contains methods to read and write textfiles from filesystem.

Comment: Sorry - to clarify - I want to write text files onto another filesystem. My survey's are hosted on a 3rd party's server. I want to incorporate code into my survey, and set up any necessary hardware/software (e.g. Apache) that would allow my survey's to write data from just this custom question to a server I own/control.

Comment: Look for Javascript and Ajax. Ajax allows you to send data asunchrosly. On your serverside, setup a server and write a script -which runs on server side- that receive the request and store it on your filesystem. You can use Python either.